# Setting email id with capitalization

Tags: email, dom, google-apps

I am setting up a domain which is in the FirstSecond.com format. Is it possible for me to set up something (on google apps) such that both the url and email appear with 'F' and 'S' in capitals. I know capitalization doesn't matter other than display, but much tougher to note that there are two words without capitalization.

I suspect this might depend on client browsers and mail apps- wanted to check the same. Thanks

Comment: are you hosting expertsexchange?

Comment: hah-hah... not really- but guess capitalization can clearly reduce some bad reads!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't guarantee how any particular browser or email app displays your domain. Chrome, Firefox, and IE (for example) will all convert to lowercase. You might consider also registering first-second.com as an alias.